# How can I make my :active pseudo element work?

Tags: css

I have a clickable `div` I created that works like a button.  I managed to create it's `:hover` state, but I can't get the `:active` state to work. I basically need the button to maintain its `:hover` style when clicked.  I would like to use CSS only. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

```css
.delete-ad-reason-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.delete-ad-reason-box i {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: red;
}


/* Here's the ":active" */

.delete-ad-reason-box:hover,
.delete-ad-reason-box:active {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.delete-ad-reason-box:hover>i,
.delete-ad-reason-box:active>i {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="#" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-10">
  <div class="mx-auto delete-ad-reason-box" id="#">
    <i class="fas fa-frown d-block"></i> Click Me
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: First of all, `:active` applies to elements that can be “activated”, which isn’t really the case for a div element to begin with. (Not sure if setting a tabindex, so that it can receive _focus_, would fix that; you might rather need to work with the pseudo class on the parent link element here.) And second, `:active` only applies while the user _is_ activiating the element, so f.e. while they press their mouse button down (but not any more after they release the button) - so this pseudo class is probably not really what you want to begin with.

Comment: Have you got any thoughts on how I may achieve what I need with the use of CSS only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use only 1 anchor tag element for this one. `:active` `:focus` pseudo element only works on `a` tag. So simplify your html structure to this one.

```css
.click-me {display:block;color:red;border:1px solid red;width:100%;padding:20px 10px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;}
.click-me:hover,.click-me:active,.click-me:focus {border:1px solid transparent;color:#fff;background:red;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="click-me">Click Me</a>
```

This is a more simplified one and you don't need to add a `div` element inside the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `: active` for a div element. You can able to achieve it via javascript only